# Numbering equation referring to another equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, labels, ref

Sorry I don't know if the title is clear.
I would like to know how to do the following:
I have an equation, lets say its number is 1.1
After a few paragraphs I want to write another version of equation 1.1 and call it 1.1b instead of 1.2.
I have no clue how to do that if I just use

```
\begin{equation}
F = ma
\end{equation}

bla bla bla

\begin{equation}
F = mg
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Do you need it referenceable as `1.1b`, or will all subsequent references be to `1.1`?

Comment: I want to reference it as 1.1b possibily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `\label` in the first equation (here, for example, `\label{eqA}`, and in the 2nd equation (`amsmath` required), use `\tag{\ref{eqA}b}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\chapter{new chapter}
\begin{equation}
\label{eqA}
F = ma
\end{equation}

bla bla bla

\begin{equation}
\label{eqB}
F = mg\tag{\ref{eqA}b}
\end{equation}

In equations \ref{eqA} and \ref{eqB}\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is just `section numbering` of your equations that automatically assigns equation numbers based on the section you are in.
Use `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` to get it done.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{equation}
\label{equation: force}
F = ma
\end{equation}

blah blah blah

\begin{equation}
F = mg \tag{\ref{equation: force}b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You need to assign a label to the first equation and in the second equation, just
refer to it with just an additional suffix `b`.
This is done by `F = mg \tag{\ref{equation: force}b}`

**Output**

[image]